# Sympy: Substitution with functions

Tags: function, operators, sympy, substitution

I have a function f: 
`f = Function('f')(x,y)`.

The output of my program is a large polynomial with terms XYf, Xf, Yf for variables X and Y. I would like to define the substitution such that

> X f(x,y) = f(x+1,y)
>
> Y f(x,y) = f(x,y+1)

Similarly, XY f(x,y) = f(x+1,y+1).

I have used the following code to define the operation of X and Y.

`poly = poly.subs(X*f, f.subs(x,x+1))
poly = poly.subs(Y*f, f.subs(y,y+1))`

Though this works with terms of Xf and Yf, it does not work with terms of XYf. XYf gives the output as Yf(x+1,y) instead of f(x+1,y+1).

How do I force Y to act on the "new" f?

Comment: Could you paste your Python code defining _poly_?

Answer (score 1):

XYf gives Yf(x+1, y) because it matches Xf and that's the first substitution you do. To replace all three in the way that you want, you should do them in an order such that you don't match later instances, like

```
poly = poly.subs(X*Y*f, f.subs(x,x+1).subs(y, y + 1))
poly = poly.subs(X*f, f.subs(x,x+1))
poly = poly.subs(Y*f, f.subs(y,y+1))
```

That way, you replace all `X*Y*f(x, y)` first, so when you replace `X*f(x, y)` and `Y*f(x, y)` it won't replace `X*Y*f(x, y)` (because they will already be replaced).

---

As a side note, in terms of code clarity, it's going to be simpler if you just define

```
f = Function('f')
```

and then explicitly write `f(x, y)`, `f(x + 1, y)`, and so on (rather than letting `f = f(x, y)` and using `subs` to create `f(x + 1, y)` and so on).